# Button (Listener) Problems with Editor Grid Panel

Tags: extjs

I have an Editor Grid and when I press the submit button it adds the total to the Amount Due field and then is disabled(This is a good thing). My problem is that I cannot re-activate the submit button each time the add button is pressed to create a new record.

My problem is with the listener for the grid. Is this the correct way to do this? If you know of a better way to do this please let me know. Here is my code:

```
var iLineItemGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    id: 'iLineItemStore',
    store: iLineItemStore,
    cm: iLineItemCM,
    cls: 'iLineItemGrid',
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    frame: true,
    //title:'Edit Plants?',
    //plugins:checkColumn,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    viewConfig: {
        //forceFit: true
        autoFit: true
    },
    //new
    listeners: {
        edit: function (editor, edit) {
            var form = edit.grid.up('form'),
                button = form.down('button[text=Submit]');

            // enable the button after the grid is edited
            button.setDisabled(false);
        }
    },

    tbar: [{
        text: 'Add',
        tooltip: 'Add the line item',
        handler: function () {
            var r = new iLineItemRec({
                i_line_item_name: '',
                i_line_item_amt: ''
            });
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            iLineItemStore.insert(0, r);
            iLineItemGrid.startEditing(0, 0);
        },
        //Should this be scope:this or scope:iLineItemGrid?
        scope: this
    }, {
        text: 'Delete',
        tooltip: 'Remove the selected line item',
        handler: function () {
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            var r = iLineItemGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCell();
            iLineItemStore.removeAt(r[1]);
        },
        //     handler: function(){
        //       iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
        //       var r = iLineItemGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelected();
        //       iLineItemStore.removeAt(r[0]); }
        //  },

        //Should this be scope:this or scope:iLineItemGrid?
        scope: this
    },

           {
               xtype: 'tbfill'
           },

           {
               text: 'Submit',
               tooltip: 'Submit the line item',
               //new
               //disabled: true,
               handler: function () {
                   iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
                   // Will this code save changes to the database?
                   //iLineItemGrid.getStore().commitChanges();
                   iLineItemStore.commitChanges();

                   var iAmountTotalForLineItems = 0;
                   var iAmountInDueField = Ext.getCmp('iAmountDue').value;
                   var tempTotal = 0;
                   var result = 0;
                   iLineItemStore.each(function (addAmount) {
                       iAmountTotalForLineItems += addAmount.get('i_line_item_amt');

                   });

                   alert('1 iAmountInDueField: ' + iAmountInDueField + ' iLineItemTotalHold: ' + iLineItemTotalHold + ' iAmountTotalForLineItems: ' + iAmountTotalForLineItems);
                   if (iLineItemTotalHold > iAmountTotalForLineItems) {
                       alert('if');
                       tempTotal = iLineItemTotalHold - iAmountTotalForLineItems;
                       result = iAmountInDueField - tempTotal;
                       alert('two: ' + result + ' = ' + iAmountInDueField + ' + ' + tempTotal);

                   } else if (iLineItemTotalHold < iAmountTotalForLineItems) {
                       alert('if2');
                       tempTotal = iAmountTotalForLineItems - iLineItemTotalHold;
                       result = iAmountInDueField + tempTotal;
                       alert('3: ' + result + ' = ' + iAmountInDueField + ' - ' + tempTotal);
                   }

                   iLineItemTotalHold = iAmountTotalForLineItems;

                   Ext.getCmp('iAmountDue').setValue(result);
                   this.setDisabled(true);
               }
               //scope:this
           }

          ]

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to assign an unique id to the Submit button. You can use the [id](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-id) property.

Then in your handler for the Add button, add the following line to re-activate the submit button.

```
Ext.getCmp('submit_button_id_goes_here').setDisabled(false);
```

Comment: Edenbauer, thanks this was helpful. Now the problem is with the 'iAmountDue' field.  I get rounding errors, like 10.14 + 10.13 = 20.26999999 instead of 20.27 Here is the code for the field
{
                            id: 'iAmountDue',
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'amount_due',
                            style: 'margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 1px; text-align: right',
                            disabled: true,
                            fieldLabel: 'Amount Due'
                        }

Comment: Edenbauer, My delete button will not work now. Do you have any ideas on how it fix this/ Thank you.

Comment: ExtJS has a boat load of useful util functions you can use to do many things. I'd suggest you read their API documentation [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-round). Re: your 2nd comment, have you changed your delete logic since you've posted your code yesterday? I'd suggest posting a new question and attach the current version of the pertinent section of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with id's. If you have two forms open with the same id's you'll have problems.
I would set a name to the button, or an action:

The submit button:

```
 {
        text: 'Submit',
        tooltip:'Submit the line item',
        action: 'submit',
        // Your other stuff...
 }
```

The add button:

```
{
        text: 'Add',
        tooltip:'Add the line item',
        handler : function(){
            var r = new iLineItemRec({
                i_line_item_name: '',
                i_line_item_amt: ''
            });
            iLineItemGrid.stopEditing();
            iLineItemStore.insert(0, r);
            iLineItemGrid.startEditing(0, 0);
            iLineItemGrid.down('button[action=submit]').setDisabled(false);
        },
        //The scope here depends on what you want the 'this' variable to be in your handler. 
        //If you want it to be the grid then give iLineItemsGrid, if you want it to be the button you don't have to give a scope. 
        //But scope: this is dangerous because the this in your case is not the grid
        scope:iLineItemsGrid
}
```

Comment: Johan, thanks this was helpful. Now the problem is with the 'iAmountDue' field.  I get rounding errors, like 10.14 + 10.13 = 20.26999999 instead of 20.27 Here is the code for the field
{
                            id: 'iAmountDue',
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'amount_due',
                            style: 'margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 1px; text-align: right',
                            disabled: true,
                            fieldLabel: 'Amount Due'
                        }

Comment: Johan, My delete button will not work now. Do you have any ideas on how it fix this? Thank you. And thanks for explaining Scope, it helps.

Comment: I'll need to know what exactly doesn't work for your delete button. But looking at your code, r[1] should probably be r[0] because if you only select 1 cell or row r[1] will be out of bounds. 
Your first question is indeed weird, I don't have an aswer for that one.